# Do we have $2\pi({n})-\pi({2n}) \geq \omega({n})$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let it be $\pi({n})$ the number of prime numbers lesser than $n$, and $\omega({n})$ the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

It seems that "almost always"
$$2\pi({n})-\pi({2n}) \geq \omega({n}).$$
The inequality does not hold for $\{1,2,4,6,10,12\}$ and using the Python script suggested in [the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226623/2-pin-pi2n-geq-omegan#comment8778425_4226623), these are the only examples up to $n=60,000$. I conjecture that those are the only cases in which the inequality does not hold, based on the increasing difference between $2\pi({n})$ and $\pi({2n})$ as $n$ grows, which seems to increase much more than $\omega({n})$.

I am stuck in finding some proof or literature on the subject, any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Have you checked $2\pi(n)-\pi(2n)\geq \log_2 n?$ It’s a stronger result because $\log_2(n)\geq \omega(n).$

Comment: By PNT that's :$$\frac{2n}{\ln n}-\frac{2n}{\ln n+\ln 2}$$

Comment: These [inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) by Dusart, together with Thomas Andrews's observation, should be enough to prove it for $n$ sufficiently large.  Then we can check smaller values  of $n$ individually.

Comment: If you use Python, it's simple to check using Sympy: `from sympy import primefactors, primepi
    
    for n in range(10**5):
        if 2*primepi(n)-primepi(2*n) < len(primefactors(n)):
            print(n)`

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee you have to ensure the error in $\pi(n)-n/\log n$ isn’t big enough, but that is a good starting heuristic for why you should expect it for large $n.$

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments! Thanks to the code provided by @dodoturkoz I have checked all the values up to $n=60184$, to get that the only exceptions to the inequality are ${1,2,4,6,10,12}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities), in 2010, Pierre Dusart showed that for $x\ge60184$, we have $$\frac x{\log x-1}<\pi(x)<\frac x{\log x -1.1}$$
We have
$$\begin{align}
2\pi(n)-\pi(2n)&>\frac{2x}{\log x-1}-\frac{2x}{\log2x-1.1}\\
&=2x\left(\frac1{\log x -1}-\frac1{\log2x-1.1}\right)\\
&=2x\frac{\log2-.1}{(\log x-1)(\log2x-1.1)}\\
&\geq\frac{1.18x}{\log^2x}
\end{align}$$
As Thomas Andrews remarked in a comment, it's enough to compare this to $\log_2x$.
It's easy to see that $$1.18\log2\cdot x>\log^3x$$ for $x>500$, say, so that these calculations confirm the statement for $n\geq60184$.

I leave it to the OP to check smaller values, but note that the product of the first $8$ primes is already greater than $60184$, so that there is no need to factor $n$ if $2\pi(n)-\pi(2n)>7$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: thanks for your great answer! As the smaller values are checked, the inequality is proved with the exceptions provided.