# On the Second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

I have recently known about the [Second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture), and I was struck when I noticed that this conjecture was very related with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226623/do-we-have-2-pin-pi2n-geq-omegan) I asked in this site.

So, my question is, is the inequality at the end of this post sufficient to show that the Second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture is correct? Is there any way to show that it is false? I have checked and found no positive integer values $x,y$ other than $x=2, y=2$ and $x=837, y=77$ for which the inequality holds, but I am not able to show that it does not hold for some $x,y\geq N_0$.

I provide some context on how the inequality was obtained.

The conjecture states that $\pi(x+y)\leq \pi(x)+\pi(y)$ for integers $x,y\geq 2$, where $\pi(n)$ denotes the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

Without loss of generality, we have that $x\geq y$. Therefore, we have that $\pi(x)\geq \pi(y)$, and $\pi(2x)\geq \pi(x+y)\geq \pi(2y)$.

As proved by user @saulspatz in the MSE post mentioned, we have that, for $x,y\geq 60184$, $$2\pi(x)\geq \pi(2x)+\log_2{x}$$ $$2\pi(y)\geq \pi(2y)+\log_2{y}$$ Therefore, we have that $$2(\pi(x)+\pi(y))\geq \pi(2x)+\pi(2y)+\log_2{x}+\log_2{y}$$ Assume that the conjecture is false and that $\pi(x+y)> \pi(x)+\pi(y)$. Then, we would have that $$2(\pi(x+y))\geq \pi(2x)+\pi(2y)+\log_2{x}+\log_2{y}$$ For $x,y\geq 60184$, and as mentioned in the MSE post, applying Pierre Dusart's bounds, we have that $$\frac {2x}{\log (2x)-1}<\pi(2x)<\frac {2x}{\log (2x) -1.1}$$ $$\frac {2y}{\log (2y)-1}<\pi(2y)<\frac {2y}{\log (2y) -1.1}$$ $$\frac {x+y}{\log (x+y)-1}<\pi(x+y)<\frac {x+y}{\log (x+y) -1.1}$$ Therefore, if the conjecture were false, we could be able to show that $$2\frac {x+y}{\log (x+y) -1.1}\geq\frac {2x}{\log (2x)-1}+\frac {2y}{\log (2y)-1}+\log_2{x}+\log_2{y}$$ Operating, we have that $$\frac {2(x+y)}{\log (x+y) -1.1}\geq\frac {2x}{\log (2x)-1}+\frac {2y}{\log (2y)-1}+\log_2{x}+\log_2{y}$$ $$\frac {2x}{\log (x+y) -1.1}+\frac {2y}{\log (x+y) -1.1}\geq\frac {2x}{\log (2x)-1}+\frac {2y}{\log (2y)-1}+\log_2{x}+\log_2{y}$$ $$2x\left(\frac {1}{\log (x+y) -1.1}-\frac{1}{\log (2x) -1}\right)+2y\left(\frac {1}{\log (x+y) -1.1}-\frac {1}{\log (2y) -1}\right)\geq\log_2{x}+\log_2{y}$$ I am not able to simplify the last inequality further to obtain something helpful to disprove it for some $x,y\geq N_0$.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$2\frac {x+y}{\log (x+y) -1.1}\geq\frac {2x}{\log (2x)-1}+\frac {2y}{\log (2y)-1}+\log_2{x}+\log_2{y}$$

Let
$$f(x,y):=\frac {2x+2y}{\log (x+y) -1.1}-\frac {2x}{\log (2x)-1}-\frac {2y}{\log (2y)-1}-\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}-\frac{\log(y)}{\log(2)}$$

Let us consider the case $y=x$.

We have
$$f(x,x)=\frac {0.4x\log(2)-2\log(x)(\log (2x) -1.1)(\log (2x)-1)}{(\log (2x) -1.1)(\log (2x)-1)\log(2)}$$
which can be written as
$$f(x,x)=\frac {x\bigg(0.4\log(2)-2\cdot\dfrac{\log(x)}{x^{1/3}}\cdot\dfrac{\log (x)+\log(2) -1.1}{x^{1/3}}\cdot\dfrac{\log (x)+\log(2)-1}{x^{1/3}}\bigg)}{(\log (2x) -1.1)(\log (2x)-1)\log(2)}$$

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\log(x)}{x^{1/3}}=0$, we can say that there is a positive integer $N$ such that for every $x$ satisfying $x\ge N$, $f(x,x)\gt 0$.

This means that your idea does not work to prove that the conjecture is true.

---

**Added** :

Let us consider the case $x=y+10$.

$$f(y+10,y)=\frac {4y+20}{\log (2y+10) -1.1}-\frac {2y+20}{\log (2y+20)-1}-\frac {2y}{\log (2y)-1}-\frac{\log(y^2+10y)}{\log(2)}$$

$$=\frac{\color{red}{g(y)}}{(\log (2y+10) -1.1)(\log (2y+20)-1)(\log (2y)-1)\log(2)}$$

where

$$\color{red}{g(y)}=(4y+20)(\log (2y+20)-1)(\log (2y)-1)\log(2)-(2y+20)(\log (2y+10) -1.1)(\log (2y)-1)\log(2)-2y(\log (2y+10) -1.1)(\log (2y+20)-1)\log(2)-\log(y^2+10y)(\log (2y+10) -1.1)(\log (2y+20)-1)(\log (2y)-1)$$

$$=(4y+20)(\log (2y+20)-1)(\log (2y)-1)\color{blue}{h(y)}$$

and
$$\color{blue}{h(y)}=\log(2)-\frac{(y+10)(\log (2y+10) -1.1)}{(2y+10)(\log (2y+20)-1)}\log(2)-\frac{y(\log (2y+10) -1.1)}{(2y+10)(\log (2y)-1)}\log(2)-\frac{\log(y^2+10y)(\log (2y+10) -1.1)}{4y+20}$$

$$=\underbrace{\bigg(1-\frac{(y+10)(\log (2y+10) -1.1)}{(2y+10)(\log (2y+20)-1)}-\frac{y(\log (2y+10) -1.1)}{(2y+10)(\log (2y)-1)}\bigg)}_{i(y)}\log(2)-\underbrace{\frac{\log(y^2+10y)(\log (2y+10) -1.1)}{4y+20}}_{j(y)}$$

$$=i(y)\bigg(\log(2)-\frac{j(y)}{i(y)}\bigg)$$

WolframAlpha says

- For $y\gt 2.96567$, $i(y)\gt 0$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-%28%28y%2B10%29%28log+%282y%2B10%29+-1.1%29%29%2F%28%282y%2B10%29%28log+%282y%2B20%29-1%29%29-%28y%28log+%282y%2B10%29+-1.1%29%29%2F%28%282y%2B10%29%28log+%282y%29-1%29%29%3E0))
- $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to\infty}\dfrac{j(y)}{i(y)}=0$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5B+%28%28%28log%28y*y%2B10*y%29%29*%28log%282*y%2B10%29-1.1%29%29%2F%284y%2B20%29%29%2F%281-%28%28y%2B10%29%28log+%282y%2B10%29+-1.1%29%29%2F%28%282y%2B10%29%28log+%282y%2B20%29-1%29%29-%28y%28log+%282y%2B10%29+-1.1%29%29%2F%28%282y%2B10%29%28log+%282y%29-1%29%29%29%2Cy+to+infinity%5D))

So, this means that there is a positive integer $N_1$ such that for every $(x,y)$ satisfying $x=y+10\ge N_1$, $f(x,y)\gt 0$ holds.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Indeed, by substitution and simplification, $f(x,x)=\frac{2x}{\log (2x)-1.1} -\frac{2x}{\log (2x)-1}-\log_2 x$, and it can be checked that $f(x,x)>0$ for all $x\geq 3638$. However, if $y=x$, the conjecture is true for that case just by the inequality $2\pi(x)\geq \pi(2x)+\log_2{x}$. Could the formula be used restricting the values of $x$ and $y$ that can be plugged in just for those for which the conjecture is not known to be true?

Comment: @Juan Moreno : I added another example.